# Custom Fieldtype: How to check save($data)

Tags: add-on-development, custom-fields, fieldtype, fields

Developing a custom fieldtype and having trouble getting the entry data to save to the `exp_channel_data` table. I know that the data passed must be a string and I am trying to catch the data at the `public function save($data)` point so I can properly construct it and pass it on.

My issue is that I can't seem to stop and see anything at that point. No `var_dump(), echo(), print_r(), exit()`, etc are having any effect.

How can I view the `$data` being sent to that method?

Answer (score 1):

I received some help in the slack forum for this one.

Short answer is I was not providing a `name` for my fieldtype during construction. I assumed this was auto-generated by EE due to back end requirements. I was wrong. lol

I added the `name` attribute to the field on creation in the format `field_id_x` where `x` is the config id. Once this was in place, the fields were processed. A little more clear documentation in the dev docs would be nice to clarify this.  ;)